# Multiline items in ExtGWT ComboBox dropdown list

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, multiline, gxt

I can't manage to make the contents of my combobox' dropdown list wrap properly.
I'm doing this:

```
private native String getTemplate() /*-{
return [ 
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class="x-combo-list-item" style="width: 450px;">',
    '{id}<br />{name}</div>',
    '</tpl>'
    ].join("");
}-*/;
```

It doesn't seem to work, the contents of the list keep overflowing the div and the rest of the string becomes hidden. And although `<br>` works, such a "solution" isn't really acceptable.
I already tried to add various `overflow`-ish css styles to my div, tried to add a table, nothing works. Any ideas?

Update: i also tried to make a nested `<div>` within `"x-combo-list-item"`, but in this case i can't select an item at all. `comboBox.setItemSelector("x-combo-list-item")` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I found an answer: you need to explicitly state the tag kind in `setItemSelector` as in `comboBox.setItemSelector("div.x-combo-list-item");`. Works great in that case.